# Syncing Two SQL Servers with one annother

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, database-replication

Is it possible to sync two sql servers?

From my understanding of SQL replication, you have a master and it simply replicates / copies its self to the non-master. Changes cant be made to the non-master DB as they will be lost.

Now I have come into the situation where we host our primary DB on a vm on the internet, and we need to some how have access to certain tables locally, mainly because some critical systems run on those tables and being in Africa our internet lines do go down fairly regularly. However there are web services which run off these tables on the internet, but it is not vital that they have the latest copy of the data.

The Idea of syncing the two spawns many ideas of issues that can be caused by it, duplicate files and out of sync entries etc. The same entity being updated on the two different servers etc. How would one deal with all of these without having human input?

However as crazy as it sounds I thought I would ask, as MS or SQL might have implemented a solution that performs this sort of service. or maybe some one can suggest an alternative solution to me.

We are making use of SQL Server 2012 Enterprise

Answer (score 1):

Look up Merge Replication for two-way synchronisation.

- [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152531(v=sql.110).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152531%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)